# Realm 3.0 OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener RxJava support

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I was reading the release notes of Realm 3.0 and i was wondering if i would receive the same notifications from the OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener in an observable or how would that work exactly if it does ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Well if you create your own Observable (or Flowable) wrapper around your RealmResults and return a pair of `results, changes` then yes

Comment: yes, thats true. I was wondering if that came out of the box

Comment: Not yet, as far as I know. Even the "how" of RxJava2 is a good question

Comment: No, we don't support it right now, but it would probably be a good addition. Any preference to how it should be named since `asObservable()` is already taken?

Comment: See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4277